# How to delay the execution of a timed task for two or more years

Tags: java, microservices

In a microservice architecture, suppose there is a business scenario where a user purchases something that will expire after two years, and the system needs to notify the user a little bit in advance.

In this case, how should we handle the situation so that the users can be notified on time even if there are many users who need to be notified?

For example, using a delayed queue of message queue will cause the messages to pile up when there are many users; using a timed task, too many users will overload the server CPU.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Just check a record in a DB.  You need some persistent record else if the service goes down, the record will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

While "microservices" do not inherently mean "REST", they usually are. And in REST you shouldn't store in memory anything that needs to survive more than one request. Two years is an extreme case, but even if it is for just 10 minutes, it should probably go to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Building up a queue for two years will just be very impractical and likely to fail if the queue contents are not persisted somewhere. Since you mention purchases I am assuming you have some sort of data store to record them either in sql or no-sql.

You can simply add purchase date/time column(s) to the table to make life easier. If you volumes are low enough for daily purchases then I would start with date based lookup only. You will need a scheduled execution of some service method say at 6am everyday that looks up purchases close to expiry i.e 7 days before 2 years `purchase_date = now - 723days` and then send rest request somewhere or publishes an event or jms message with order number and purchase_date as content for each purchase order. This will then be picked up by event/message listener somewhere and processed accordingly i.e. send a notification to customer. To avoid sending duplicate notifications you should also persist the expiry notifications in a database and ensure you check that notification has been sent for purchase id before sending it again.

If you ever reach a situation where you are processing thousands of orders a day and don't want to publish large number of events in one go then extend the functionality to filter by purchase timestamp and process chunks of purchases multiple times a day by changing the lookup condition.

This is just general idea of such requirement and you will have to fine-grain a lot of implementation details such as what happens if your email server is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quartz job and configure it to use persistent mode in database (JDBC JobStore) to not loose information and also it is suitable for clustering mode.

Quartz checks periodically the database for the nearest task (configurable parameter) if the time comes, it will process the notification.

You can configure the thread pool size in order to avoid overload.